# Symfony2: Placeholder in DropDown Box is selectable

Tags: symfony, placeholder, dropdownbox

I have a date field and I want to put a placeholder for example for Year.
So my code is in my formtype

```
->add('birthday', 'date', array(
                'placeholder' => array('year' => 'YYYY', 'month' => 'MM', 'day' => 'TT'),
                'years' => range(1899,2100)
            ))
```

And when i look at the ouput, the placeholdertext in my year-Dropdown is selectable!? So I can choose `"YYYY"` What do I make here wrong?! THANKS FORY ANY HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I think this link can help you to do what you wanted to do :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format

Answer (score 0):

I came across on Symfony 2.8 the same issue on Symfony 2.8 and it seems that `'required' => false` will make the placeholder selectable.
`'required' => true` will make it disabled.